# Does this generic method signature make sense?

Tags: java, generics

Legacy code:

```
public <B extends IBox> List<B> getBoxList(String key)
```

There is no way for the method to know which subtype the caller is actually expecting, so there is no sensible way to fulfill this contract.

**Important: there is no way to infer the expected subtype from the key**.

Therefore the signature should be:

```
public List<IBox> getBoxList(String key)
```

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you think that the second option is better?

Comment: It is possible to call generic method as `foo.<TheType> getBoxList (...)`.

Comment: I claim that it's not possible to fulfill the contract, you can of course always cast the result.

Comment: @Roland: It is possible to fulfill the contract -- just `return null;` -- it's just not very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Consider the following code which won't even compile under Java 8, but will compile under Java 7 with a warning. The caller is actually expecting a list of BlueBox from the BoxDB:

```
List<BlueBox> boxList = boxDB.<BlueBox>getBoxList("123");
```

But what he actually gets is a List of RedBox. So the method is not delivering what it promises.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BoxDB boxDB = new BoxDB();
    List<BlueBox> boxList = boxDB.<BlueBox>getBoxList("123");
    for (IBox box: boxList) {
        System.out.println(box.getClass().getName());//prints "RedBox"
    }
  }
}

interface IBox {
    String getKey();
}

class RedBox implements IBox {
  String key;
  public RedBox(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }
}

class BlueBox implements IBox {
  String key;
  public BlueBox(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }
}

class BoxDB
{
  public <B extends IBox> List<B> getBoxList(String key) {
    List<B> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add((B)new RedBox("123"));
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that like this:

```
public List<? extends IBox> getBoxList(String key)
```

Comment: This is unrelated to both of those.

Answer (score -1):

There is a subtle difference between the two. The first **retains** the type while the second flattens the type to it's interface. By moving to the second you are essentially discarding some information that may be useful to the caller.

```
interface IBox {

}

public static <B extends IBox> List<B> getBoxList1(String key) {
    return null;
}

public static List<IBox> getBoxList2(String key) {
    return null;
}

class ABox implements IBox {

}

class BBox implements IBox {

}

public void test() {
    List<ABox> aBox = Test.<ABox>getBoxList1("Hello");
    List<BBox> bBox = Test.<BBox>getBoxList1("Hello");
    // Not allowed.
    List<ABox> cBox = Test.getBoxList2("Hello");
    List<IBox> dBox = Test.getBoxList2("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Right, how would you implement the method body of `getBoxList1`to instantiate the expected return type?

Comment: @Roland - Perhaps the key would direct me to a factory or constructor? The essence here is that the first retains the maximum amount of type information while the second discards some of it. I'll try to post a more realistic demonstration.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: `B` and the `key` are completely independently determined by the caller.

Answer (score -1):

To explain this lets start with an example

```
public RedBox implements IBox{
//implementation here
}

public BlueBox implements IBox{
//implementation here
}
```

Now suppose one case I need list of RedBoxe and YellowBox then my call as per the first code would be

```
List<RedBox> redBoxList = getBoxList(redKey);
List<YellowBox> yellowBoxList = getBoxList(yellowKey);
```

But in the later case this would be:

```
List<RedBox> redBoxList = (List<RedBox>)getBoxList();//Since it returns List<IBox>
List<RedBox> redBoxList = (List<RedBox>)getBoxList();
```

So the former code is much efficient in ensuring type safety. 
Former code makes more sense. To read more about generics refer to Effective Java.

Comment: Right, how would you implement the method body of getBoxList to instantiate the expected return type?

Comment: The former is definitely very type-unsafe. `List<YellowBox> yellowBoxList = getBoxList(redKey);` is perfectly legal.

Comment: @Roland it depends. If the implementation of method is something like a factory or service it can decide the return type based on the key passed to method getBoxList (red) .  Also as the return type dictates that whatever user returns should be implementing IBox interface. Why do you need a type argument separately if it is not necessary. The type argument makes sense in most of the cases not all of them.